# Invalid activities specified in the ActivityTransitionRequest

Tags: android, google-api, android-pendingintent, activity-recognition, android-securityexception

I'm trying to use ActivityRecognition. However I get an error when i'm trying to get a transition update for DetectedActivity.TILTING or DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN. For all the other activity types I don't have problems.

Here is my code to create the ActivityTransitionRequest

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityRecognizedService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Task<Void> task =
            ActivityRecognition.getClient(this).
                    requestActivityTransitionUpdates(createTransitionsRequest(), pendingIntent);

    task.addOnSuccessListener(
            new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "success");
                    // Handle success
                }
            }
    );

    task.addOnFailureListener(
            new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "failure", e);
                    // Handle error
                }
            }
    );

    // ActivityRecognition.getClient(this).requestActivityUpdates(1000L, pendingIntent);
}

private ActivityTransitionRequest createTransitionsRequest() {
    List<ActivityTransition> transitions = new ArrayList<>();

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.STILL)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.STILL)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.WALKING)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.WALKING)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.RUNNING)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.RUNNING)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    // The following activity transitions will result in an exception.
    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.TILTING)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                        .build());

    transitions.add(
            new ActivityTransition.Builder()
                    .setActivityType(DetectedActivity.TILTING)
                    .setActivityTransition(ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                        .build());

    return new ActivityTransitionRequest(transitions);
}
```

This is the IntentService I'm using.

```
public class ActivityRecognizedService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = ActivityRecognizedService.class.getSimpleName();

    public ActivityRecognizedService() {
        super("ActivityRecognizedService");
    }

    public ActivityRecognizedService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if(ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            handleDetectedActivities( result.getProbableActivities() );
        }
    }

    private void handleDetectedActivities(List<DetectedActivity> probableActivities) {
        for( DetectedActivity activity : probableActivities ) {
            switch( activity.getType() ) {
                case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE: {
                    Log.e( TAG, "In Vehicle: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE: {
                    Log.e( TAG, "On Bicycle: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT: {
                    Log.e( TAG, "On Foot: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.RUNNING: {
                    Log.e( TAG, "Running: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.STILL: {
                    Log.e( TAG, "Still: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.TILTING: {
                    Log.e( TAG, "Tilting: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.WALKING: {
                    Log.e( TAG, "Walking: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN: {
                    Log.e( TAG, "Unknown: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception i'm getting:

```
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: SecurityException: Invalid activities specified in the ActivityTransitionRequest! at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzm.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.zzo(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which class does `ActivityRecognizedService` extend ??

Comment: @SantanuSur IntentService

Comment: lel `IntentService` is a Service *NOT* an `activity`,  how are you using `requestActivityTransitionUpdates` method with it ??

Comment: @SantanuSur I'm not sure what your telling me. I've updated my question with the code for the IntentService. Can you tell me what i should change?

Comment: `For all the other activity types I don't have problems` ...are you using the same `pendingIntent` along with them ?? i mean  `Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityRecognizedService.class);`

Comment: @SantanuSur Yes its all the same PendingIntent. Actually I'm not receiving any intent yet in my service with requestActivityTransitionUpdates. However it works with 'requestActivityUpdates' so I think that the service is not the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per official [android developer document,](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions.html#register)

> The Transition API supports the following activities:
>
> ```
> IN_VEHICLE
> ON_BICYCLE
> RUNNING
> STILL
> WALKING
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The Transition API supports only the following activities: 
- IN_VEHICLE
- ON_BICYCLE
- RUNNING
- STILL
- WALKING

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Transition for `UNKNOWN` and `TILTING`. They are not supported.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).